# JPA Entities Synchronization Mechanism

Tags: java, jpa, notifications

I'm writing an application (a CMS) using JPA/Hibernate, and in a single UI i have multiple components that might show the same entity (each one will show only a portion). I also have multiple UIs, in multiple sessions for multiple users.

Some of these components can also edit the entity, and all others component should always show the up-to-date entity.
A gross way would be a periodic refresh, but this is laggy and heavy, so i come up with a synchronization mechanism for jpa.

Using an interceptor (the hibernate one, since the jpa one is dumb) i can listen all the transactions, all the new/updated/removed entity and send notifications to every component interested in.
I also can catch derived transactions, meaning that if a component, responding to a notification, modify in any way the entity (opening a new transaction) i can resend the notification (only a delta).
This is becouse a component may modify the entity in a such way that another component may need to modify again it. (just a stupid example: a component set the birth date, and another re-calculate the age)

**ps.** *The notifications are dispatched only after the transaction commit. This is mainly becouse*

> The section 3.5 of JPA specification states:
>   “In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or Query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence context. A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.”

*so the listeners would be useless if notified inside the transaction.
And (to grin and bear it) to group up modified entities and notify them all together.*

This notification mechanism is growing complex, and i was wondering:

Why jpa has not such mechanism? 
I'm inventing something strange? 
How "real applications" solves this problem?

Comment: I don't really get it: why don't you synchronize your components on the UI level, so that, when a component changes something in the entity, all the dependent components reload the data (dependencies defined on the UI level)? On the other side, it could be so, that you could split the entity into different smaller entities, according to your business logic in UI. Or another idea to save all the changes from all components with the same request, and refresh the data only in the UI when needed.

Comment: @AndreiI not only the UI may modify a entity, it could be also modified by a batch operation and moreover a UI instance should not have a reference of another UI. The data model / data layer should tell when there are modifications. The entity could not be splitted, it's a well designed entity, but a component may need to show only the name, and another also more properties. "refresh the data only in the UI when needed", and how do i know when it is ?

Comment: Let's say we have UI components Component1 (with fields Field1 & Field2) & Component2 (with fields Field1, Field3 & Field4). Do you mean that you have the case that Component1 & Component2 are shown to different users? The Component must connect anyway to the data-layer somehow, in order to find out if something changed. How are you doing it right now, if you do not refresh periodically the Component?

Comment: @AndreiI Yes, Component1 and 2 might be shown to different users. They are connected to the data layer, trough my sinconization mechanism, but they do not know each other (component1 don't knows 2 and vice versa). Right now the data layer intercept the modifications trough an Hibernate interceptor and notify all registered components of the modification (a component register itself when created).

Comment: EclipseLink (I know you aren't using it) has a cache coordination feature that allows sending out the changesets after the transaction commits, and any process can register to receive these changes.  It also can hook into database notifications to invalidate cached objects for changes.  While the first is provider specific and I'm not sure Hibernate has similar feature, the second is a database feature you might be able to leverage instead of using JPA.  Another might be to use JTA afterCompletion events and provider specific features to access changes.

Comment: @Chris interesting, i did not know of this EclipseLink capability, i'll look into to see how it implemented it. For the hook, don't think i need it, only the application can change the database. I don't really know how JTA works, and the last time i've tryed to understand it i was left with an headache...i'll try again, it seem the most proper way